# Publishing error: ORA-00600

Tags: publishing, 2009

I am working with Tridion 2009 R5, when I publish any page I get the following error:

> Error: ORA-00600: código de error interno, argumentos: [25027], [4],
>   [1548580204], [], [], [], [], []

in the Event Viewer I find more information but I don't know which is the problem.

> Error: ORA-00600: código de error interno, argumentos: [25027], [4],
>   [1548580204], [], [], [], [], []

```
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

StackTrace Information Details:
   en Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.RenderResolvedItem(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, List`1 processedItems, PublishTransaction publishTransaction, TransportPackage transportPackage)
   en Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.RenderRequestHandler(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   en Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.ProcessPublishTransaction(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   en Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueMessageHandler.DoWork()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. It may help people to help you if you update your question with anything you have tried so far.

Comment: Searching for the ORA-00600 error code showed me this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511534/oracle-ora-00600, what version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This sure looks like a serious problem with your Oracle database. A quick Google Search on Oracle 00600 brings up the following information:

> Every occurrence of an ORA-600 should be reported to Oracle Support. Unlike other errors, you can not find help text for these errors. Only Oracle technical support should diagnose and take actions to prevent or resolve damage to the database.

In other words, call up your DBA and find your Oracle Developer Network login information. Quite some info available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51support-453463.html).